# Why using the 'new' keyword in class shows this error?

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors

I'm trying to create a dynamic 2D array of objects using the **new** keyword. This was my initial code, which worked ok.

```cpp
class Foo{
    public:

    static Foo ** make2D(int m, int n) {
        Foo **a = new Foo*[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            a[i] = new Foo[n];
        }
        return a;
    }
};


int main() {

    Foo ** x = Foo::make2D(2, 2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Then I decided to add a constructor inside the class. It looks like this:

```cpp
Foo(int a, int b){}
```

The rest of the code doesn't change, but now i'm not able to create the 2D array. I'm getting an error on instruction `a[i] = new Foo[n];`:

> No matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo()'

It seems that the `new Foo[n];` instructions calls the constructor, expecting two parameters, and receiving none.

What can I do to fix the error? Maybe I should use something like malloc?

Comment: The tl;dr, as is so often the case in C++, is "don't use C-style cruft". Make an `std::vector` and everything will work out.

Comment: I suppose you could use placement new in order to handle this situation, as the linked answer suggests. But the ***real*** answer here is: don't even use `new` in the first place. It is rarely needed in modern C++. Use `std::vector`, and it will handle everything correctly. Use `reserve()` to effectively allocate the underlying storage, then `emplace_back` to construct each `Foo` in the "array". Mission accomplished, that was pretty easy, wasn't it?

Comment: *I'm trying to create a dynamic 2D array of objects using the new keyword* -- `#include <vector>... std::vector<std::vector<Foo>> a(m, std::vector<Foo>(n));`  --

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I guess I should start to use vector; seems to be easier and more flexible.

Comment: Well worth the time. [Here's a neat example of it in action.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301)